# what are the uses of main, default and launcher in manifest file in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity, launcher, intentfilter

```
<activity android:name="ApiDemos">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

-Can any one explain about main, default and launcher what are the use of those properties in manifest for activity if used more than 1 activity in my project?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**android.intent.action.MAIN** matches all of the activities that can be used as top-level entry points into an application.

**The LAUNCHER** category says that this entry point should be listed in the application launcher.

**The default** category is required for the `Context.startActivity()` method to resolve your activity when its component name is not explicitly specified.

So category `LAUNCHER + action MAIN` let the icon for this Activity show up in the launchers list of available "applications".

You can have this `intent-filter` on more than one Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and all of them will show up in the list off "applications".

Intents are documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and IntentFilters [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html).

Comment: confused on what you mean.  default is needed to be implicit.  main is needed to mark it first in task. launcher is needed to make icon visible ? if no launcher means icon will never be visible in app drawer/screen so cannot be launcher by user using touch.  but it can be started from other activity as such since its marked as default even if not marked main.  its just that launcher needs main.  so there is no independent use of main ?

Comment: reading further may be learned that explict intent does not need intent-filter.